# Report total number of question views not as title-text on mobile devices?

Tags: feature-request, tooltips, views, accessibility

I was using my phone to check in on a question I asked that has over 1000 views.  I was curious exactly how many views there were, but it's measured in kviews.  On a PC I could just use the title-text to see how many views there are, but on an Android you can't hover over something to see its title text.

Would it be possible to have some way to view the total view count on a mobile device as a precise number rather than in kviews?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about the deprecated mobile site, which is no longer accessible.