# Unable to view exact view count on questions with many views on touchscreen devices

Tags: feature-request, views, accessibility, responsive-design, touch-screen

For questions with many views (when a suffix is used) there isn't any way to get the exact view count on touchscreen devices. [E.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/339911):

> [image]

On devices when the mouse pointer is available you can see the exact view value on the tooltip:

> [image]

This is not a duplicate of [Report total number of question views not as title-text on mobile devices?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84006/report-total-number-of-question-views-not-as-title-text-on-mobile-devices) because that question is asking about the deprecated mobile site, while this question asks about the modern responsive site when viewed on a mobile device. This is also not a duplicate of [How can I view the actual number of views for a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385980/how-can-i-view-the-actual-number-of-views-for-a-question) because that question is asking about it *in general*, and the answer there, which is to browse the site from a desktop and hover over the view count, doesn't address this question.

Comment: It's abbreviated (effectively rounded) precisely because at those thresholds the _exact_ count is irrelevant (and on busy questions like that, probably different by the time the mouseover appears anyway). The mouseover is a nice extra but I can't imagine what you would do differently if you knew the count of views on that question was 46,920 or 47,121.

Comment: @bobble interesting... the old question was about mobile-web version of the site that is deprecated currently since responsive mode is enabled by default for all SE sites. So in terms of the time when the old question was asked - this one is not a dupe. But if we drop away [mobile-web] tag - they can be linked as a dupe. I think the community should decide what to do with that situation. Maybe we need to ask a new question how to deal with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I view the actual number of views for a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385980/282094) and [Hovering over "kviews" should show the number of views like hovering over a number does](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161393/282094) - it used to be shown exactly: [Wrong view count for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14118/282094)

Comment: @Rob no, none of those is duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

There's no good way to view the exact view count if you can't use a mouse (e.g. mobile users or those with a motor impairment who can't use a mouse). However, I made this bookmarklet which will help you out:

```js
javascript:{alert(document.querySelector("#content > div > div.inner-content.clearfix > div.d-flex.fw-wrap.pb8.mb16.bb.bc-black-075 > div:nth-child(3)").title);}
```

Comment: This is helpful, but it doesn't solve the underlying problem, which is that the site design (like mobile UI design generally) is unhelpful.

Comment: @phoog I agree that it should be fixed. However, they've got an awfully big accessibility backlog, most of which is higher priority than seeing the exact view count, and most of their focus lately has been on non-structural changes via the Stacks framework. (For an example of something that really doesn't work, try adding a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/414907/6083675). IIRC mobile devices are blocked from creating/editing them, and keyboard users are blocked from using the toolbar entirely.)

Comment: I am not sure browsers for mobile devices even support bookmarklets either…

Comment: @user3840170 1) Bookmark the current page. 2) Replace the URL with the bookmarklet, making sure you don't lose the starting `javascript:`. // If you want instructions for a specific browser, I can see what I can find. I personally tested this in iOS Chrome, which also has synced bookmarks from desktop.