# Duplication by an old post with obsolete tag

Tags: discussion, support, tags, duplicate-questions, obsolete-information

There's an old and currently obsolete tag [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) (if used for non-chat questions). It so happened that current site behavior (responsive design) works the same as for an old mobile site. Should we close new questions related to the modern (2023) design as a duplicate of an old (when mobile-web was used) question?

Should we remove the obsolete tag from such old questions in case of closing? Should we leave the old one intact for historical reasons?

I'm really not sure how to correctly handle such situations.

This question is based on [my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387733/unable-to-view-exact-view-count-on-questions-with-many-views-on-touchscreen-devi#comment1293115_387733), so you could get more relevant context by the link.

Comment: FYI, there is a [tag:responsive-design] tag, for questions related to responsive design on the site/network.

Comment: "Should we close new questions related to the modern (2023) design as a duplicate of an old (when mobile-web was used) question?" – I suspect this may depend on the specific questions, and whether the info in the old post is no longer applicable to the current responsive design. (I suspect the [mobile-web] tag should stay on any questions specifically about the old mobile web interface, though, since that is what the tag was intended for.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it wasn't clear what interface was being referred to (since the "desktop" version has had that behavior too for the longest time), I removed the tag, replacing it with [accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility) to indicate this is a bigger issue — it affects anyone without a mouse, including keyboard-only users on desktop. As such, it makes sense to close a newer question as a duplicate of it. (Remember, duplicates aren't bad.)

With other questions, it's a judgement call.  If you ignore the tags, does it look like a duplicate? (Likely a duplicate then.) Is this something that used to work for you in the responsive view but recently broke? (Likely not a duplicate.)

Answer (score -5):

I suggest to leave the [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) for historical significance since there are also obsolete questions and questions with historical significance, and the questions with historical significance cannot be deleted as they are locked. So I suggest that this obsolete tag should not be deleted.